# Threading module python stopping and re-start threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I was looking how to stop a thread on python using the thread module, and I found that this method is not provided by the module. I have seen some tricks to implement a way to stop the threads but nothing of this worked for me.

My program have a main window that shows every function on it, and one of this functions opens another window that do a "function2" with a button.
I want to be able to do things, or not let the windows freeze while "function2" is running, so I have used `threading.Thread` to define the "function2" and called it using `Thread.run()` method.
This, works great, but when "function2" is done, I cannot re-run the function because of the threads can only be started once.

I need a solution to this, if someone can help me, I would be glad.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-run"? Just start new thread? If you wish to stop a thread then you have to check periodically some shared state in that thread.

Comment: @freakish Doing the same action again, like if function2 print numbers from 1 to 10, once the function has printed all numbers, I want to let the function2 run again to print from 1 to 10.

Comment: Ok, and what is the problem? Why can't you start another thread with function2? Perhaps you should show us some code and tell us what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: Yes, the problem is not to start another thread, is that I have a button like this `ttk.Button(loginpanel,text='Initfun2',command=fun2.start)` and the method called is this `fun2 = threading.Thread(name='funcion2',target=funcion2)` so when I press the button, it try to start the same thread.

Comment: Obviously your method is incorrect. What you should have is `ttk.Button(..., command=start_fun2)` and then `start_fun2 = lambda : threading.Thread(name='funcion2',target=funcion2).start()` (or via `def`).

Comment: Note that this is heavily simplified. Actually you should use a threadpool. Spawning a thread on each click is bad.

Comment: I'm not familiarized with lambda, so, with lambda everytime I press the button, it will generate another thread instead of having the same 'name'?

Comment: You may think about lambda as a "short function". The same can be written as `def start_fun2(): threading.Thread(name='funcion2',target=funcion2).start()`. The point is that you have to create a new `Thread` object on each call to the command, not start the same `Thread` object over and over again.

Comment: Ok, so, due that this method is not completely correct, you recommend me try to do with a threadpool instead of creating a different thread everytime I click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on comments. What you have is

```
fun2 = threading.Thread(name='funcion2',target=funcion2)
ttk.Button(loginpanel,text='Initfun2',command=fun2.start)
```

which basically creates one thread and tries to re-run it on click. There is no such thing as re-runing threads so instead you have to create a new thread on click:

```
def fun2():
    threading.Thread(name='funcion2',target=funcion2).start()
ttk.Button(loginpanel,text='Initfun2',command=fun2)
```

While this is better it has another drawback: what if someone starts clicking the button like mad? You want to restrain the number of threads to use. For that using [a thread pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) is a good option:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

THREADPOOL = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
def fun2():
    THREADPOOL.submit(funcion2)
ttk.Button(loginpanel,text='Initfun2',command=fun2)
```

This code is for Python3.x. For Python2 I think you need some external library.

Comment: Ok, now I understand everything, thanks for your help, now, if you let me ask you another question. If I use a threadpool and fix the limit in 5 instead of  10 (only because it's less) and I clicked 5 times the button, and function2 run correctly and finish it's five counts, I won't be able to click the button again?

Comment: @DavidGonzálezBlazman You will be able to click the button. What will happen is that the call to `funcion2` will be scheduled and it will be fired as soon as the threadpool has free resources (which will happen once previous calls to `funcion2` end). Also note that you need locks if you share state between these function (e.g. when you update globals).

Comment: I was reading the documentation you linked, it's possible using the shutdown() method?

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried the code now with some modifications to adapt, and it works exactly as expected!

Comment: @DavidGonzálezBlazman ThreadPool has a queue and creates "worker threads", these are running **all the time** in the background. Those threads are waiting for a message submitted via `.submit` and they are processing it. The `shutdown()` method is intended for the entire ThreadPool. Once you call it, it will stop accepting new messages, it will wait for all workers to finish what they are doing and then kill all threads and clean up after itself. If the button is clickable during whole app's lifetime then you should not call `shutdown()` at all.